# Generate JSON key Value dictionary using SQL Server with multiple rows

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

Trying to figure out how to convert multiple rows of data to a single row of KeyValue array.

Raw data:

| id | FkId | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 83713 | 1024180 | Name1 | Value1 |
| 83714 | 1024180 | Name2 | Value2 |

Desired result:

```
{ "Name1":"Value1", "Name2":"Value2" }
```

I have tried different combos using Json Path and JSON_Array.. neither are resolving to what I need.

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAY(s.name,s.value) AS result 
FROM tbl s 
WHERE FkId = 1024180
```

Result is two rows with wrappers:

```
row 0 ["Name1","Value1"],
row 1 ["Name2","Value2"]
```

Tried:

```
SELECT s.name, s.value 
FROM tbl s 
WHERE fkid= 1024180 
FOR JSON PATH
```

Result:

```
[{"name":"SpaceSubType","value":"Fee Earner"},{"name":"Department","value":"Property"}]
```

Is there a reasonable way to get the output I am trying for?

#### results

Applying Yitzhak's recommendation I am super close to what I need however the json path is now escaping the manually generated dictionary. Any idea if possible to somehow trim those escape chars out?

##### formatted

```
select 
sa.Id as 'id',
s.id   as 'Sid',
(SELECT ('{' + STRING_AGG('"' + sp.name + '": "' + sp.value + '"', ',') + '}') as barf FROM  tbl sp where foo = s.id) as properties
     from TblA sa
     inner join TblB s on s.id = sa.Sid
     Where sa.Sid = '04000772'
     For Json path, 
     INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
```

##### result

```
[
    {
        "id": "04000772",
        "Sid": 1024180,
        "Properties": "{\"Name1\": \"Value1\",\"Name2\": \"Value2\"}"
    }
]
```

as per comments below.. this is the ticket to escaping the string once built.

`…s.id as Sid, json_query((select '{'+string_agg('"'+string_escape(name, 'json') +'":'+isnull('"'+string_escape(value, 'json')+'"', 'null'), ',')+'}' from tableX)) as properties`

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: hells bells @lptr.. thats the ticket... sweet man Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

It will work starting from SQL Server 2017 onwards.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT PRIMARY KEY, FkId INT, name VARCHAR(20), value VARCHAR(20));
INSERT @tbl (id, FkId, name, value) VALUES
(83713, '1024180', 'Name1', 'Value1'),
(83714, '1024180', 'Name2', 'Value2');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT '{' + STRING_AGG('"' + name + '": "' + value + '"', ',') + '}'
FROM @tbl
WHERE fkid = 1024180
```

**Output**

```
{
    "Name1": "Value1",
    "Name2": "Value2"
}
```

Comment: huzzahh... so close.. any idea how I could trim out the escape chars ? 
Its part of a larger json path query.. and when I output, it sees the  already converted and escapes it as string...

Comment: Its part of a larger json path query and escapes it as string... 
ex: 
```
[
    {
        "id": "04000772",
        "sId": 1024180,
        "properties": "{\"Name1\": \"Value2\",\"Name2\": \"Value2\"}"
    }
]
````
SQL 
```
select 
Convert(varchar(20),sa.Id) ,
s.id    as 'SId',
(SELECT ('{' + STRING_AGG('"' + sp.name + '": "' + sp.value + '"', ',') + '}') as barf FROM  tbl sp where foo = s.id) as properties
from t1 sa
inner join t2 s on s.id = sa.Id
 Where sa.Id= '04000772'
 For Json path, 
 INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
```

Comment: you need to escape it properly `STRING_AGG('"' + STRING_ESCAPE(name, 'json') + '": "' + STRING_ESCAPE(value, 'json' + '"', ',')`